# Retrieving comma sperated record from sql

Tags: sql, mysqli

I have tree tables in a database

1. Student (student_id,first_name,last_name)
2. Employee (employee_id,full_name,last_name)
3. Message (message_id,sender_id,reciever_ids,msg)

When student/employee sends a message to a students's or employee's reciever_id containt comma spertated value like `1-1,2-45,1-25`).

`2-45` shows its an employee and 45 is his id and in "1-25" 1 shows its a student and 25 shows its is his id.

now how can i triverse that reciever_ids to get the relevant record?

Comment: If you added a separate table (`recipients`) it would be a far better design - you shouldn't be shoving multiple data items into a single column - even better is to have `student` and `employee` have a common base table (`persons`), or to have `recipient_students` and `recipient_employees` tables.

Comment: As just one example of the problems this design has - try to find an efficient way to find all messages that were sent to Student 19.

Answer (score 0):

If it's just a delimiter issue, you can wrap the whole value in quotes:

```
`receiver_ids`='1-1,2-45,1-25',
```

Comment: I totally misunderstood the question in it's original form. It makes much more sense now you've edited it. Incidentally, if you change the question when you performa n edit it makes for a confusing thread.Damien_The_Unbeliever is correct, the database structure is not ideal.

Comment: @turnerscafe its not just the delimeter issue the issue is how to break that record so that retrieve from thier respective table

Comment: @dragon112 - You could always use LIKE '%-XX,%' (where XX is the id)but you would need to append a comma to the end of the field. This is not really ideal and you should review your database schema as Damien_The_Unbeliever said. I'd use this as a last resort if you do not have permissions or the ability to change the database to be better structured.